# access form from another funcion

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, render, try-except

Question is..

I have static page profil.py:

```
def profil(request, pk):

    context = {}
    person = User.objects.get(id=pk)

    try:
        person.profesor
    except Profesor.DoesNotExist:
        context['ucenik'] = Ucenik.objects.get(id=person.ucenik.id)
    else:
        context['profesor'] = Profesor.objects.get(id=person.profesor.id)



    return render(request, "profil.html", context)
```

and this:

```
def profesor(request):
   profesor = request.user.profesor
   forma = ProfesorFormaSlika(instance=profesor)
   context = {'forma':forma}
   return render(request, 'pocetna_profesor.html', context)
```

Question is, How can I access {{ forma }} in HTML page from `def profesor` in `def profil`?

Comment: Explain better your problem with more specific details.

Comment: I just need to upload user picture on his profile page.
Problem is, when i go to profile.html page and put {{ forma }} for upload picture(i created in forms.py), i dont know how to print that form on profile.html, because that form is in def(profeso) function

Comment: Read this topic, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.